# Linear Approximation: Find the linear approximation at a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question:
f(x,y)=√(7+2xy)

Find the linear approximation at (3, -1)

My answer:

So I took the partial derivative at x and y, and I got Fx = y/(√(7+2xy)) and Fy = x/(√(7+2xy)). Evaluating for this, I get Fx(3,-1)= -1 and Fy(3,-1) = 3. Then L(x)= -x + 3y + 1, but I'm wrong. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

make a change of variable $x = 3+h, y = -1 + k.$ then $$z = \left(7+ 2(3+h)(-1+k)\right)^{1/2} = \left(1-2h+6k+\cdots\right)^{1/2}= 1 + \frac 12(-2h+6k)+\cdots = 1-h+3k+\cdots$$

the planar approximation of $z$ at $(3, -1)$ is $z = 1 -(x-3) + 3(y+1).$

Answer (score 0):

Use $$L(x) - f(3, -1) = -(x-3) + 3(y-(-1)) = 3 - x + 3y +3.$$

Comment: No, it is still wrong.

Comment: You just need an extra +1.  You want the plane that goes through the point (3,-1,1) that has the right slope in the x and y direction.

Answer (score 0):

Linear approximation is given by: $L(x)=f(x_0,y_0)+ f_x(3,-1)(x-3) + f_y(3,-1) (y+1)$

You forgot to multiply by (x-3) and (y+1)